# Why is putting the node into the top of this queue segfaulting?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, queue

My program has these structs:

```
typedef struct Entry { // node
  void *data; // whatever our data is, goes here
  struct Entry *next; // next node
} Entry;

typedef struct {
   int (*compare)(const void*a, const void *b); // compare func
   Entry *top; // head
   Entry *bottom; // tail
} *Queue;
```

And uses them to create a queue with this:

```
Queue create( int (*cmp)(const void*a, const void*b) ) {

   Queue Q = NULL;
   Q = (Queue)malloc(sizeof(Queue));

   Q->top = NULL;
   Q->bottom = NULL;

   Q->top = malloc(sizeof(Entry));
   Q->bottom = malloc(sizeof(Entry));

   Q->compare = cmp;

   return Q;
}
```

Inserted using this:

```
void insert( Queue queue, void *data ) {
   // start at the top
   Entry *slot = queue->top;
   Entry *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Entry));
   newNode->data = data;
   newNode->next = NULL;

   // is it an entirely empty queue?
if (que_empty(queue)) {
      // put our data into the dummy slot
      queue->top = newNode;
   }
}
```

Run from a given main tester file that is correct and cannot be modified (the data to be inserted is in a global variable):

```
int main( void ) {
        Queue up, down, fifo;

        up = create( cmp_int64_ascend );
        if( up == NULL ) {
                fputs( "Cannot create ascending queue\n", stderr );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        down = create( cmp_int64_descend );
        if( down == NULL ) {
                fputs( "Cannot create descending queue\n", stderr );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        fifo = create( NULL );
        if( fifo == NULL ) {
                fputs( "Cannot create FIFO queue\n", stderr );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        puts( "Testing the ascending queue" );
        process( up );

        puts( "\nTesting the descending queue" );
        process( down );

        puts( "\nTesting the FIFO queue" );
        process( fifo );

        destroy( up );
        destroy( down );
        destroy( fifo );

        return( 0 );
}
```

When I try to run this, it starts endlessly repeating what looks like a pointer address (ex., 18087952) and crashes.  The line I'm struggling with is queue->top = newNode.

How can I assign newNode into the top of the queue?

Comment: Your code isn't consistent. `main` is calling `que_create`, but you've shown us a function called `create`.

Comment: This is not correct. `Q = (Queue)malloc(sizeof(Queue));`. You are not allocating enough memory. You need to use `Q = (Queue)malloc(sizeof(*Q));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line not correct.

```
Q = (Queue)malloc(sizeof(Queue));
```

You are not allocating enough memory. You need to use

```
Q = (Queue)malloc(sizeof(*Q));
```

This is a good programming style to follow while using `malloc`. You are less likely to make errors in calculating the size.

```
var = malloc(sizeof(*var));
```

Regarding the insert error... You have

```
void insert( Queue queue, void *data ) {
   // start at the top
   Entry *slot = queue->top;
   Entry *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Entry));
   newNode->data = data;
   newNode->next = NULL;

   // is it an entirely empty queue?
   if (que_empty(queue)) {
      // put our data into the dummy slot
      queue->top = newNode;
   }

   // Where's the code to deal with the case when the queue is not empty????

}
```

This should work:

```
void insert( Queue queue, void *data ) {
   Entry *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Entry));
   newNode->data = data;
   newNode->next = queue->top;
   queue->top = newNode;
}
```

Comment: This is helpful, thank you, but I'm still having the same issue when attempting to insert a new node into the top of the queue.

Answer (score 3):

```
Queue Q = NULL;
Q = (Queue)malloc(sizeof(Queue));
```

`Queue` is a pointer type here, so you're allocating the size of a pointer instead of the size of a struct.

You probably shouldn't give a pointer type a name like `Queue`, which gives no indication for being a pointer - this is just confusing and leads to errors like the one above.

It's better to name the struct itself `Queue`, and use `Queue*` where you need a pointer.